# Format suffix in Silex restful framework

Tags: php, rest, silex

I am starting building a RESTful api which supports multiple response formats. I want to recognize the requested response format with the Accept header and alternatively with a file suffix appended to the request url.

E.g.
`/api/endpoint` with includes `Accept: application/json*` and
`/api/endpoint.json` should result in the same json response.

`/api/endpoint.xml` should result in XML response.

I did not find any documentation about response formats in Silex, so how to start and is it possible to allow also the file suffix for format recognition?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do this logic in a controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from [Silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/providers/serializer.html#usage):

```
use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Provider\SerializerServiceProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$app = new Application();

$app->register(new SerializerServiceProvider());

// only accept content types supported by the serializer via the assert method.
$app->get("/pages/{id}.{_format}", function (Request $request, $id) use ($app) {
// assume a page_repository service exists that returns Page objects. The
// object returned has getters and setters exposing the state.
$page = $app['page_repository']->find($id);
$format = $request->getRequestFormat();

if (!$page instanceof Page) {
    $app->abort("No page found for id: $id");
}

return new Response($app['serializer']->serialize($page, $format), 200, array(
    "Content-Type" => $request->getMimeType($format)
));
})->assert("_format", "xml|json")
  ->assert("id", "\d+");
```

To get json response by default you can use something similar to:

```
$app->get("/pages/{id}{_separator}{_format}", function (Request $request, $id) use ($app) {
    //...
})->assert("id", "\d+")
  ->value("_separator", ".")
  ->assert("_separator", "\.|\/")
  ->value("_format", "json")
  ->assert("_format", "json|xml");

// /pages/1 => json reponse
// /pages/1.json => json response
// /pages/1.xml => xml response
// /pages/1/json => json response (as a bonus)
// and etc.
```

Also see [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#global-configuration) to configure this behavior globally.